# Best way to increase width to nodes with OrgChart

Tags: javascript, html, css, orgchart

I'm using [OrgChart](https://github.com/dabeng/OrgChart-Webcomponents) to draw tree-like structures.
The default string text will be truncated when long string is occured (e.g. Biostatistics and Bioinformatics Core).

[image]

My idea is to change the property `width` of `.orgchart .bioinformatics` in CSS file. However, if I have a **dozen nodes** in my cluster, I don't want to manually adjust the width of each node. How can I automatically increase nodes width then show string completely without truncate in each cell?

---

**[Reproduce the Issue]**

```js
let datascource = {
  'name': '中心主任',
  'title': 'Director',
  'className': 'top-level',
  'children': [{
      'name': '表觀基因體核心',
      'title': 'Epigenomics Core',
      'className': 'epigenomics'
    },
    {
      'name': '蛋白質體核心',
      'title': 'Proteomics Core',
      'className': 'proteomics'
    },
    {
      'name': '定序核心',
      'title': 'Sequencing Core',
      'className': 'sequencing'
    },
    {
      'name': '藥物研發核心',
      'title': 'Drug Discovery Core',
      'className': 'drug'
    },
    {
      'name': '幹細胞核心',
      'title': 'Stem cell Core',
      'className': 'stem'
    },
    {
      'name': '免疫核心',
      'title': 'Immunology Core',
      'className': 'immunology'
    },
    {
      'name': '生物統計及生物資訊核心',
      'title': 'Biostatistics and Bioinformatics Core',
      'className': 'bioinformatics'
    }
  ]
};

var orgchart = $('#chart-container').orgchart({
  'data': datascource,
  'nodeContent': 'title',
  'direction': 'b2t'
});

document.querySelector('#chart-container').appendChild(orgchart);
```

```css
#chart-container {
  font-family: Arial;
  height: 320px;
  max-width: 1110px;
  border-radius: 5px;
  overflow: auto;
  text-align: center;
}

.orgchart .bioinformatics {
  width: 200px !important;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/orgchart/2.1.3/css/jquery.orgchart.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/orgchart/2.1.3/js/jquery.orgchart.min.js"></script>
<div id="chart-container"></div>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to auto-resize the content of all nodes:

```
#chart-container {
  font-family: Arial;
  height: 320px;
  max-width: 1110px;
  border-radius: 5px;
  overflow: auto;
  text-align: center;
}
.orgchart .node {
  width: auto !important;
}
```

`.orgchart .node` is the base class of all nodes so you only have to add `width:auto`. No need to use `.orgchart .bioinformatics`.

I left an example in CodePen: https://codepen.io/elopezp/pen/jONrWbN

Hope it helps =).

Comment: This method will increase the width of all nodes. The expected result should auto-resize all nodes width but do not display truncate text strings.

Comment: @PennyLiu I updated my answer. You have to add the base style .orgchart .node and override it in your content bioinformatics. Regards

Comment: Thanks for your reply. If I have a **dozen nodes** in my cluster then I must add lots of additional class names (e.g. `bioinformatics`) on it to resize cell. Is there any trick that I don't need to set any class names but resize it?

Comment: In that case just leave .orgchart .node style with the property "width: auto", delete all custom classes like bioinformatics and that's all. It worked for me.

Comment: I forgot to add `!important` in class `.orgchart .node`. Also you can use nodeTemplate instead nodeContent, I left that code in codepen just comment out nodeContent and uncomment nodeTemplate. Regards man.

Comment: Good and reliable answer. That’s exactly what I wanted =).

Answer (score 1):

Try overriding the `.google-visualization-orgchart-table` class of the google orgchart.

```
.google-visualization-orgchart-table tr td.google-visualization-orgchart-node div{
    width: 250px!important;
}
```

But the above code will increase width of all nodes in orgchart.

This worked for me.

Comment: I added above code snippet but it doesn't work for me.